# Configuring client certificates on IIS8 - Error 403.16

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate

I am trying to implement client certificate authentication on IIS 8. I have deployed my configuration on a development machine and verified it working as expected there. However after setting up on the server, whenever I navigate to the site and am prompted for the client cert, I select it and immediately get the 403.16 error. The failed requests log gives the error code 2148204809 and message "A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider."

I have a valid client cert and also a valid CA cert. The CA cert is installed in Trusted Root Authorities on the Computer account of both the server and the client machine, and the client cert is installed in the Personal area of the Current User account on the client machine.

The client cert is signed directly by the root CA and as I said, both are valid. There are no other certs in the chain and there are no intermediate certs in the Trusted Root Authorities area.

The IIS configuration has sslFlags = SslNegotiateCert and iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication is enabled.

The server is not configured to send a CTL and we have SendTrustedIssuerList = 0.

I cannot see why the client cert should not be trusted.

Comment: which certificate store did you install the certificate in on the server?

Comment: Sorry the CA cert is in the computer account on the client and server, and the client cert in in the Current User account

Comment: does the account under which your app pool is running have permission to access the CA cert on the server?

Comment: No, I had tried it with both the app pool identity and also the identity of a local admin account that typically administers the certs

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. It worked for me after I checked the "Disable Certificate revocation Lists (CRL)" in the properties of the self signed certificate in the Local computer trusted root CA store.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place Root CA into Trusted root certificates under Current user certificates at your client station.
If I simulated your situation my personal certificate was reporting error, because there was no root CA to be found.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501810)